# Replacement for Sonicwall TZ series firewall

Tags: firewall, router, wifi, sonicwall

I am looking for a relatively cheaper alternative to the Sonicwall TZ series firewall/wireless router device.
The main features I am looking for are:
1. Wireless router capability on a separate interfaces/subnet. Multi-interface: WAN,  LAN and WLAN.
2. Hardware firewall appliance

Any suggestions?

Comment: There looks to be 3 models in the TZ series, all at different price levels. Which one exactly are you looking for a cheaper alternative to?

Answer (score 2):

If you're at all comfortable with Linux I'd recommend looking into utilizing of the many packages out there for this. I'm personally fond of [PFSense](http://www.pfsense.org).

If you've got an aging PC you can easily turn that into a pretty powerful router/firewall solution for very minimal costs.